# Using optimization for a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Question:

A tangent line is drawn on the graph of $y=\ln x$ for $0\lt x\lt 1$. A right triangle is thus formed in the fourth quadrant. If we regard the area of this triangle has a positive value, find the maximum area of the triangle.

I tried to put the equation for the area of a triangle in terms of $x$, and then differentiated it, but I don't think that was the right approach, and I'm pretty sure I didn't do it correctly:

$$y=\ln x$$ 
$${1\over 2}xy$$
$${x\ln x\over 2}=A$$
$${d\over dx}{x\ln x\over 2}={d\over dx}A$$
$${2(x\ln x)'-2'(x \ln x)\over 4}=0$$
$${2-2x\ln x\over 4x}=0$$
$${1-x\ln x\over 2x}=0$$
$$1-x\ln x=0$$
$$x=1$$
And when I put $x$ back into the original function I just get $y=0$, and I know that can't be the right solution since that would mean that the triangle has an area of $0$.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial error is in setting $y=\ln x$.  This is true on the curve, however, your area formula should be $A=\frac12xy$ where $x,y$ are the intercepts of the tangent on the axes, not a point on the curve.

---

So, suppose that the tangent is drawn at the point where $x=a$.  It therefore passes through the point $(a,\ln a)$ and has gradient $1/a$.  Its equation is therefore
$$y-\ln a=\frac1a(x-a)\ ,$$
which simplifies to
$$x-ay=a-a\ln a\ .$$
The intercepts of this line on the axes are
$$x=a-a\ln a\ ,\quad y=(\ln a)-1\ ,$$
and noting that the latter is negative, the (positive) area of your triangle is
$$A=\frac{|xy|}2=\frac{a(1-\ln a)^2}{2}\ .$$
You should now be able to finish the problem by calculating $\frac{dA}{da}$ and then solving the equation
$$\frac{dA}{da}=0$$
to find $a$.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Let the point $(a,b)$ be that at which the line $(T)$ is tangent to the curve. Then, $\operatorname{slope} (T) = 1/a$. Consequently, $(T)$ is given by:

$$y = \frac1{a}x + b - 1$$

It meets the $y$-axis at $(0,b-1)$ and the $x$-axis at $(a(1-b),0)$.

As $a < e$, $b= \ln(a) < 1$. So, $b-1 < 0$. Writing $b= \ln(a)$, the area of the triangle is:

$$A(a) = \frac{a\left( 1-\ln(a) \right)^2}{2}$$

Consider $f(x) = \frac{x\left(1 -\ln(x) \right)^2}{2}$, and find its maximum (or supremum?) on $]0,1[$.